# Which ParseException may be thrown on signup/login attempt

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm developing an Parse based Android app and now working on signup and login screens, but I don't know which `ParseException` should I handle.

I wanna give the user the right feedback for each error and there's no documentation at all about wich code I should look for on `SignUpCallback`or `LogInCallback`.

Is there any place where I can find it or should I test all cases I wanna handle and check the code?

Comment: Yep, I got this, the question is what codes should I be looking for (like `CONNECTION_FAILED`), which ones may be thrown on each callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure if I'm handling all possible errors, but these are the ones I got in my tests:

For signup: `CONNECTION_FAILED`, `EMAIL_TAKEN` and `USERNAME_TAKEN`.

For login: `CONNECTION_FAILED` and `OBJECT_NOT_FOUND` (for unregistered and pass missmatch).

There are also these: `EMAIL_MISSING` and `PASSWORD_MISSING`, but I'm not even handling these because they are client side prevented.

I hope this helps.

**Update:**

I recently found [this](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide#errors) link that shows every error code possibly returned by Parse, although it still doesn't say when they can happen.